# Python version issues while importing OSQP with ROS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros

Have been trying to install the osqp package by referring to OSQP documentation and successfully installed using python v3.7.

I now want to run a node in ROS that supports v2.7 and have no idea how to redirect python to use osqp installed with newer version.

Have already tried matching the python versions but no luck there. Any help is appreciated.